# How to point Appharbor to child folder of Github repository

Tags: github, appharbor

I have one private repository on GitHub folder and I would like to push over [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) and for that I have created application over there and with below option I have mapped GitHub repository.

> Configure GitHub to deploy to AppHarbor

However I got failed status and noticed that I need to point AppHarbor application to child folder (WWWroot- where my web files resides) and currently it tries to map with root and results in error. So How can I point AppHarbor to child folder of Github repository?

**Update**

I am getting below errors on apphabor after mapping github repositry

```
D:\temp\4j3jxorb.0qb\output\_PublishedWebsites\WebMatrixWebsite\src\web.config(65): error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

I think on root directory there is no solution files so it will be treated as webmatrix project. However on github I have put source code of asp.net website in **src** folder as well as **wwwroot** folder with published version so how appharbor will consider to build first?

Answer (score 2):

AppHarbor will always build the contents of the entire repository. Judging by the name of the folder, you're not committing source code with a solution file. Consider using that approach, as that will make it easier to control what AppHarbor deploys. Details here: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/build-process-and-solution-file-convention

Answer (score 0):

I came here thinking I'd have trouble with getting AppHarbor to set the application root to a subdirectory like the OP. However, I just pushed a repository with one file at wwwroot/index.htm and to my surprise, AppHarbor automatically found the file and displayed it, no configuration needed.